# Angular invoke a factory function within the same factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller, I invoke a factory function that needs to call itself recursively. The code worked when they were just simple javascript functions not defined within the factory, but I am trying to isolate them a bit better.

This is what a snippet of code looks like in the controller:

```
myApp.controller('VisionCtrl', ['$scope', 'AppFactory', function ($scope, AppFactory,) {
    var promiseTaxo;
    promiseTaxo = AppFactory.getTaxonomy("vision3", "Vision Type");
}])
```

and in the factory module:

```
myApp.factory('AppFactory', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q, TaxoFactory) {
    return {
        getTaxonomy: function(group, termSet) {
            ... lots of code ....
            if (termSet.length > 0) { getTaxonomy(group, childTermSet) }
        }
    }
}])
```

This is super simplified, but the idea is that in the getTaxonomy function, if I find children node, I recursively call myself. There is a whole lot more stuff going on where I handle the asynch nature of the processing and the promises, but when I put this code outside the factory, it works just fine.

I just don't know how to invoke the getTaxonomy inside the getTaxonomy!

Comment: `getTaxonomy` is not defined, try `this.getTaxonomy`. Or define the object first, then use `obj.getTaxonomy` and `return obj` at the end. Or give your function a name to use for recursion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either call `this.getTaxonomy()` as @elclanrs mentioned or change up your factory a bit so you can call it from inside:

```
myApp.factory('AppFactory', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q, TaxoFactory) {

    var AppFactory = {
        getTaxonomy: function(group, termSet) {
            ... lots of code ....
            if (termSet.length > 0) { AppFactory.getTaxonomy(group, childTermSet) }
        }
    }

    return AppFactory;
}]);
```

Comment: Defining the internal object that contains all the functions did the trick - thanks, Note that this.getTaxonomy() did not work - undefined, I don't understand why, probably has something to do with how the injector works.